# Is there any danger slicing pickles hours before frying them?

Tags: frying, pickles

I am frying pickles later tonight, and I would like to pre-cut all my slices to fry. Is there any reason I shouldn't cut them then put them back in the jar for later?

Comment: May I ask why you want to cut them in advance.

Comment: I just wanted to cut them in advance in order to prepare for a big meal. I realize now that it might have been a dumb question. I ended up cutting them then putting them back in the jar and everything worked out fine!

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is no danger.**

Just slice the pickles then put them back in the jar or alternatively wrap them in foil and place them back in the refrigerator until you need them.

Comment: I'd personally avoid foil .... it's not all that long of a time, but in general, acid and metals should be avoided.